# a quick notational doubt clearing in the definition of Markov chain on uncountable state space

Tags: notation, markov-chains, markov-process

1. [Equation 7.18 or next few](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Etgk/mc/book_chap7.pdf) I found the notation $\int K(x_k, dx)$, my question is it same as $\int K(x_k, A)dx$ or the  $\int K(x_k, \cdot)dx$ is much better? Thank you for any explanation or how to get understand that notation because I always saw from school days or later stages: $\int\text{something } dx$ rather than $\int(\text{something }, dx)$
2. Also, if one can show some intuition behind the notation of the definition of $n$ step transition kernel, that would be great, I am bit confused.

Comment: It is a notation for integrating against the measure $A \mapsto K(x_k,A)$. It is better notation than either of your alternatives.

Comment: Would you be a bit more detailed? Thank you!

Comment: There's not really much more to say about that question. You can't write this as something $dx$ unless that measure has a density with respect to Lebesgue measure (because that's what just putting $dx$ on the end actually means), and there's no requirement that it does. I agree it is weird notation to put the $dx$ inside the argument like that, but you get used to it.

Comment: As for your second question, what's the confusion? Is it that the $n$ is written in the exponent? That is sensible when you think about the finite state space case with a time homogeneous chain, where the one step kernel is just a matrix, and the $n$ step kernel is the $n$th power of that matrix.

Comment: Hi@Ian, could you please tell me what is $P_i$ in definition 3.1? https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2007/REUPapers/FINALFULL/Casarotto.pdf, in particular why there is an $i$, would it be just $P$?

Comment: That subscript is a common shorthand for conditioning on $X_0=i$. Sometimes it's put in the superscript instead.

Comment: So $P_i(X_n=i)$ means the probability of visiting $i$ in $n$ step starting from $i$ right? If you see def 3.3 once.

Comment: The probability that you are at $i$ after $n$ steps starting from $i$. This is different from whether your $n$ step path starting from $i$ had another visit to $i$ in it at any time.

Comment: I did not get the last sentence.

Comment: "the probability of visiting $i$ in $n$ steps starting from $i$" is ambiguous. What you are looking at is the probability that you are at state $i$ after $n$ steps have passed starting from $i$, $P(X_n=i \mid X_0=i)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ian, my last question is in Theorem 5.3 of the note, $m_i=E_i(T_i)$ the expected return time to the state $i$, does he mean expected first return time? I did not find the definition of ''expected return time to the state $i$'' could you please define it for me. Thank you.